# Ambari api POST complaining CSRF protection

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I am trying to set hbase property through Ambari API using following command

`curl -u "admin:admin" -i -X POST -d '{"type": "hbase-site", "tag": "version3", "properties" : {"hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size" : "0.6"}}' https://abct.net/api/v1/clusters/xyz/configurations`

But keep getting following error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 107
Content-Type: text/plain
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-ms-hdi-active: 10.8.18.29
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
User: admin
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
Set-Cookie: AMBARISESSIONID=2e8ortl32j1p7zdjatigdgvg;Path=/;HttpOnly; path=/; secure
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 18:19:38 GMT

{
  "status" : 400,
  "message" : "CSRF protection is turned on. X-Requested-By HTTP header is required."
}
```

What  am missing here ?

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 8):

Turns out you have to [add the request header](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-4337) to the request for anything other than a GET request.

You can add the header with

```
curl --header "X-Requested-By: my_computer_name"
```

Or

You can [disable this feature](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/35145/how-to-resolve-csrf-protection-error-while-adding.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in c# Rest client. Using Brig's answer fixed it:

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "yyyyy"),
        };

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            //"X-Requested-By: my_computer_name"
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-By","my_computer_name");
```